# Spring Boot 2.5+ with JDK 17 - maven surefire doesn't execute existing tests

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

When changing the Spring Boot 2.2 application to 2.5.5 with JDK 17, the Surefire test plugin does not start any existing tests. This is the message:

```
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Why does it not start any existing tests? The names of the tests are *Test.java.

I saw similar behavior when explicitly adding the Surefire plugin with a version higher then 2.19. Spring boot test starter will have a newer surefire plugin.

Maven version is 3.6.3.
On the path is jdk17.1.0.

```
<java.version>17</java.version>
<maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
```

I looked at similar questions and saw that the path of the test folder should be below 'src'. Yes, it is.

[image]

In the folder it is the same:

[image]

Below both folders is a 'java' folder.

The Surefire is not explicitly in the pom.xml because it is in the spring-boot-test starter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what kind of test exist in you project ? integration test or/and unit test? Can you give more detail on your context?

Anyway, from version 2.4.0 of spring-boot, JUnit 5’s Vintage Engine Removed from `spring-boot-starter-test`.

It is said in the 2.4.0 release note page https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes:

> If you upgrade to Spring Boot 2.4 and see test compilation errors for JUnit classes such as `org.junit.Test`, this may be because JUnit 5’s vintage engine has been removed from `spring-boot-starter-test`. The vintage engine allows tests written with JUnit 4 to be run by JUnit 5. If you do not want to migrate your tests to JUnit 5 and wish to continue using JUnit 4, add a dependency on the Vintage Engine, as shown in the following example for Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you! The tests are all unit tests that run in Surefire v1. 19.0.The names of the tests are *Test.java.

Comment: Wow! This actually saved my day today! But I also consider using Junit5 - it will require more changes but will be a good investment for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Other situations what you will see no tests run:

- Main and test are not in the same folder
- Test file names do not end in *Test.java
- There is an older surefire plugin, like 2.14.x. Just use a newer version, like

  org.apache.maven.plugins
     maven-surefire-plugin
     3.0.0-M5